# Display the itemPrice from the table to the php page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the different item prices from the SQL in my PHP code. 
    I am done with the total price of the items but not with displaying the individual price.
    here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `orderitems`';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$orderitems = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();



$order_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'order_id');

 $total="SELECT SUM(itemPrice)   as sum
        FROM orderitems 
        WHERE orderID = $order_id
        group by orderID";
    $statement = $db->prepare($total);
    $statement->execute();
    $total_order= $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Total of the order</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Total for an order 
        </h1>
        <h4>
            <label>orderID : </label> <?php echo $order_id ;?>


        </h4>
        <p>The total for this order consisting of :</p>
        <p>
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            do{
                 echo "one item at : " ;
                 foreach ($orderitems as $order);
                 echo $order['itemPrice']; 
            }
            while ($i == $order_id);
            ?>
        </p>


        <p> is : <?php foreach($total_order as $row) {
       echo $row['sum'] . ' <br />';
    } ?>  
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

i want to get a result like this :
    Total for an order

```
orderID : 3

The total for this order consisting of :

one item at: 549.99 and,
one item at: 499.00

is : 1048.99
```

but with this code I am only getting like this :

```
Total for an order

orderID : 3

The total for this order consisting of :

one item at : 549.99

is : 1048.99
```

and here is my database table
[image: i just want to show item price when we select that orderid]

```
pls help me


i want to display the each item price from the table who has same orderID .
```

Comment: first fetch who have orderId what ever you want then total them using php code. do not use sql query to add them.